# Nested PUT under multiple ID's

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, swagger

Multiple simulations running with ID's, which PUT information (building) also categorised by ID, to API. How do I PUT "building" with its id, inside the simulation that is posting it also with an id.

I have used /simulation/{id} which address simulation by id. Then to PUT variables I also use /building/{id} to declare a building and which one by id.

```js
/sim_launch/{sim_id}:
    put:
      operationId: "putLaunchById"
      parameters: 
      - name: "sim_id"
        in: "path"
        description: "Id of launch simulation"
        required: true
        type: "string"
      - in: "body"
        name: "sim_launch"
        description: "The ID of the vehicle to return"
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/launch'
      responses:
        201:
          description: "Note was correctly created"
        400:
          description: "bad input parameter"enter code here

  /building/{id}:
    put:
      operationId: "postBuilidingById"
      parameters:
      - name: "id"
        in: "path"
        description: "id of building simulation"
        required: true
        type: "string"
      - in: "body"
        name: "building_array"
        description: "building array holder"
        schema:
          $ref: '#/definitions/building'
      responses:
        201:
          description: "Note was correctly created"
        400:
          description: "bad input parameter"
```

Comment: Can you clarify the question please? It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: I have multiple Simulations running at the same time, that POST information such as building, junction and so on... each obj posted by a simulation has an id (/building/{id}) but im not sure how to reference each one of the objects under its specific simulation. eg simulation 001 has posted building 024. So if i GET i can say in simulation 001 building 024 (simulation/{id}/building/{id}) and get the data of the obj.